# Moving changesets between branches

Tags: mercurial

I have the following situation in my repositorium:

```
    / b1
----
    \ b2
```

`b1, b2` means branch1 and branch2 respectively.

I would like make some changes to branch and I would like to apply this changes to b2 as well. What is the best (and recommended way) to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, there's two ways:

## 1 Merge

You can merge one branch into the other. But that means basically carrying over all changes to the other branch. You might not want that.

## 2 Graft

More likely what you need: You simply copy the selected changesets from one branch to the other. Checkout the branch which is missing the changes and then graft them:

```
hg graft --rev XXX
```

You can give the revision argument several times.